# How do you get uiSignal to work on nested async calls?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using the rxjs library within a component, which has something called uiSignal. I'm trying to use this to displaying a 'loading' screen during subscription calls. This seems to work fine on simple ones, but where there's a nested subscription, it doesn't wait for the nested call to return.

Here's an example:

```
this.Service.DoSomething(this.thing)
            .uiSignal({ uiLabel: 'Loading', debugInfo: '' }).subscribe(thing => {

    this.nestedMethod();
}

nestedMethod() {

    this.Service.DoSomethingElse(this.OtherThing).subscribe(otherThing => {
        // Do Something Else
    }
}
```

However, the loading page only shows for the context of the 'DoSomething' subscription and will not wait for the DoSomethingElse subscription to return. I've tried adding the uiSignal on the nestedMethod 'DoSomethingElse' subscription as well but this doesn't work either.

Basically I want it to display until the nested method has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I ended up using Observable.forkJoin as per here: https://netbasal.com/rxjs-six-operators-that-you-must-know-5ed3b6e238a0

Answer (score 0):

Try using `switchMap`:

```
this.Service.DoSomething(this.thing)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((res) => this.nestedMethod())
  )
  .uiSignal({ uiLabel: 'Loading', debugInfo: '' })
  .subscribe(thing => {});

nestedMethod() {
  return this.Service.DoSomethingElse(this.OtherThing);
}
```

This should in theory make the `uiSignal` bit wait for both observables to complete.

Comment: .pipe isn't an option on my observable. SwitchMap is, but it expects a type of ObservableInput<{}> whereas my nestedMethod is a void. The problem is, my DoSomehingElse is being subscribed to as well (so another async call).

Comment: Which RXJS version are you using?

Comment: Looks like version 5.1.0

Comment: Try upgrading to 5.5 or higher and `pipe` should be available.

Comment: It feels like I shouldn't have nested subscribes but as the 2nd doesn't need any parameters from the 1st flatmap doesn't seem right either. Upgrading to 5.5 maybe an option but probably not.

Comment: You can combine the observables using forkJoin or zip if that feels better.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing